# QuickOSM shows OVERPASS ERROR when running a query

Tags: qgis, quickosm

When I try to run a query for a map of New Mexico, it says that there is an overpass error because query has run out of memory at 2048 MB. I have tried some solutions such as increasing the timeout all the way up and adding maxsize=800000000000 but when I do that it says there is a download error. What can I do to get pass this? I am using QGIS Desktop 3.4.15 (Long Term Madeira) QuickOSM plugin

Comment: It happens to me when I try to download all the layers. Try to select less layers and save them directly in a Geopackage

Comment: You must upgrade your QGIS. 3.4 is not maintained and old. The version of QuickOSM is old on this version of QGIS as well. A lot of performance issues has been fixed since the version provided in QGIS 3.4 https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/ "versions" tab. You are still using QuickOSM 1.17, while we are at version 2.2